# Android: Why won't my emulator launch?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I've created a simple test project and a generic emulator `TestDevice`. However, I can't get the app to launch.

I just get a console-type window (oddly placed partially off screen) and nothing happens.

I am developing in Eclipse (Helios 3.6) on Windows.

Here's the log:

```
[2011-05-11 10:08:04 - androidtest] Android Launch!
[2011-05-11 10:08:04 - androidtest] adb is running normally.
[2011-05-11 10:08:04 - androidtest] Performing androidtest.AndroidTestActivity activity launch
[2011-05-11 10:08:04 - androidtest] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'TestDevice' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2011-05-11 10:08:04 - androidtest] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'TestDevice'
[2011-05-11 10:08:14 - androidtest] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-05-11 10:08:14 - androidtest] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

**EDIT**

Thanks for all the tips!

- I am targeting Android 3.0 (API level 11)
- I've ensured that I specified `androidtest.AndroidTestActivity` as the Launch Action
- I've killed the `adb` process and restarted from Eclipse (even restarted Eclipse itself)
- I've also launched the emulator manually from `Window > Android SDK & AVD Manager`

Still, same problem.

Comment: from logcat, it still seems in waiting state, an application is still not launched. Just kill your emulator and run your emulator again. other problem can be that your application may not have any launcher activity

Comment: I guess you tried to launch from eclipse. Can you specify more details about your system? Os, eclipse and android versions? Did you try launching it from cl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. It wasn't a problem with the setup.

The emulator takes forever and a day to start up, that's all.

Comment: I've also seen that the Emulator of 3.0 takes too long to startup and also gives error of insufficient memory even if I allocate 2000MB of memory at the time of creation!!

Answer (score 2):

[Optimizing Apps for Android 3.0](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/optimizing-for-3.0.html) offers a tip on maximizing productivity with the emulator:

> **Tip:** To improve the startup time for the emulator, enable snapshots for the AVD when you create it with the SDK and AVD Manager (there's a checkbox in the AVD creator to Enable snapshots). Then, start the AVD from the AVD manager and check Launch from snapshot and Save to snapshot. This way, when you close the emulator, a snapshot of the AVD state is saved and used to quickly relaunch the AVD next time. However, when you choose to save a snapshot, the emulator will be slow to close, so you might want to disable Save to snapshot after you've acquired an initial snapshot (after you close the AVD for the first time).

To disable the "Save to snapshot" option for AVDs launched by Eclipse add "-no-snapshot-save" to the Default emulator options under Preferences > Android > Launch.

There's a couple of features related to snapshots that are accessible via the command line, but unless you need to do some serious snapshot management, it's not particularly useful.

Answer (score 1):

First start your emulator (window->Android SDK and AVD manager) Then run your application. Make sure the sdk versions are compatible!

Answer (score 1):

it happens some times try to restart your adb. if on windows try to end adb service from task manager and run from eclipse again.

Answer (score -1):

I always just delete my AVD phone and just make a whole new one. Then launch that and it'll open.